# Put file on S3 with AWS SDK 2 & Cognito for unauth users using iOS SDK 2

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I want to upload a file to one of my S3 buckets.

In my app I have:

### In my app delegate

```
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-1:05da3124-9aab-abd9-081231a31")
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

### An Upload function

```
func uploadFile(fileURL: NSURL, type: MediaType) {
    var uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest.body = fileURL
    uploadRequest.key = fileURL.lastPathComponent
    uploadRequest.bucket = "xxx.xxx.dev"
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            log.debug("Upload failed with error: \(error)")
        } else {
            log.debug("Object \(uploadRequest.key) uploaded with \(task.result)")
            XXXRESTManager.sharedInstance.doRegisterUpload(uploadRequest.key, type: type)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

### A Policy attached to my Unauthenticated role in my identity pool:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3: PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx.xxx.dev"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:CreatePlatformEndpoint",
                "sns:Subscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The connection to cognito is correct (i now have one unauthenticated user in AWS console.

However I still get a permission denied when I try to upload a file.
What did I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused the issue, but I managed to make it work.
The code in the question IS correct.

Answer (score 1):

`AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest` might need more permissions than just PutObject to work. Have you tried giving broader permissions for S3 on your policy? Probably it needs at least GetObject, but try first with `"Action": "s3:*"` so we can make sure the problem is in that part.

Comment: I have an other bucket that use the exact same permissions successfully. I tried anyway, without success.

Comment: Since you mention that you have two buckets, I'm wondering if you are also reusing the same role in two identity pools. Note that roles are tied to an identity pool, so the same role won't work if you try to use it in a different identity pool.